# How to take Excel file uploaded from website and import data to SQL Server programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public void ImportClick(object sender, EventArgs e) //the button used after selecting the spreadsheet file
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile) //ASP.Net FileUpload control
    {
        if (fileUpload.FileName.EndsWith(".xls", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || fileUpload.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Excel sheet = new Excel(fileUpload.Open()); //not sure how to do this part

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["our_database"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name SELECT * FROM " + sheet, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteQuery(); //Intellisense only has "ExecuteNonQuery()" method, but that's for T-SQL
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            error.Text = "File must be either *.xls or *.xlsx";
            error.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error.Text = "No file was selected";
        error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of classes and interfaces in the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx), and I don't know which one to use.

I know making the Excel object, along with the SQL command, probably won't be as easy as what I have here, but those are the two things I need help with.

Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using Microsoft Jet Engine.

```
private static void UploadExcelToDB(string p)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Log("Opened connection to DB");
                }
                SqlBulkCopy sbk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
                sbk.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                sbk.DestinationTableName = DbTableName;
                DataTable excelDT = new DataTable();
                OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnString.Replace("xFILEx",p));
                excelConn.Open();
                if (excelConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Log("Opened connection to Excel");
                }
                OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ["+ExcelTableName+"]";
                cmdExcel.Connection = excelConn;
                oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                oda.Fill(excelDT);
                if (excelDT != null)
                {
                    Log("Fetched records to local Data Table");
                }
                excelConn.Close();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE ICN_NUGGET_REPORT_RAW",conn);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                Log("Trying to clear current data in table");
                int i = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Log("Table flushed");
                Log("Trying write new data to server");
                sbk.WriteToServer(excelDT);
                Log("Written to server");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            SendErrorReportMail();
        }
        finally
        {
            #if (DEBUG)
            {
            }
            #else
            {
            string archive_file = ArchiveDir+"\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-Hmmss") + ".xlsx";
            File.Move(p, archive_file);
            Log("Moved processed file to archive dir");
            Log("Starting archive process...");
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
```

This is how `ExcelConnString` looks like:

`public static string ExcelConnString { get { return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=xFILEx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";";} }`

HDR=YES - this means that if you have column names in spreadsheet it will be treated as target table column names for matching each other.

Comment: Is the DataTable a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable or System.Data.DataTable?

Comment: It's a System.Data.DataTable as I am avoiding using Interop.

Comment: I would add, if both SQL and Web servers have access to a common folder where the file can be stored, then OPENDATASOURCE and OPENROWSET could be used as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686. Also, I would advise against using Office interop on the web server due to threading and interactivity.

Comment: @AdrianK. I got a `InvalidOperationException` with the message of `The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type smallint of the specified target column.`  The first column in the database table is for the year, which is the smallint. But the spreadsheet doesn't have that column, so is there a way to add it into the bulk insert?

Comment: Bulk copy requires target table have exact structure as in excel. I'd make a new (proxy) table an set a trigger there to insert proper values into target table

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of creating an instance of excel.application class and writing codes to loop through the cells. And using SQL insert query to copy the rows one by one to the SQL table. I'm still working it out anyway and would paste the code when i'm done.